# deploy catboost model shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, catboost

I have a shiny app that I'm trying to deploy on the https://shinyapps.io page, however the app uses the catboost package. Which can be installed in R as indicated in [https://catboost.ai/en/docs/installation/r-installation-binary-installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnJfT.png)

```
install.packages('devtools')
devtools::install_url('https://github.com/catboost/catboost/releases/download/v1.1.1/catboost-R-Windows-1.1.1.tgz', INSTALL_opts = c("--no-multiarch"))
```

While in linux it is as follows:

```
devtools::install_url('https://github.com/catboost/catboost/releases/download/v1.1.1/catboost-R-Linux-1.1.1.tgz', INSTALL_opts = c("--no-multiarch"))
```

Example shinyapp

```
library(shiny)
library(catboost)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("go", "Go"),
  numericInput("n", "n", 50),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  randomVals <- eventReactive(input$go, {runif(input$n)})
  output$plot <- renderPlot({hist(randomVals())})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

image of the error when trying to deploy

[image]

Comment: I need to challenge the premise of the question. The packrat package can use `devtools::install_github`, version 1.4 or later.

Comment: It still doesn't work for me.

Comment: What was "it"???. The link to what you claimed was to the install instructions is just a screen grab of your error message. We don't even know what you did to get that message. The link to the Linux-specific installation works without any error or warning for me. The example shiny app doesn't seem to call `catboost` and runs without error, producing a histogram..So I guess I need to vote to close this dreadfully incomplete question as not reproducible and lacking needed code and data for error debugging.

Comment: The error screenshot appears when the shiny app is published, not when the package is installed locally. The error I show is reproducible with the code I attached, if you try to deploy the app on shinyapps.io.

Comment: @IRTFM the renv or packrat looks for all library/require calls and build the dependency tree so later a server can install them. The library(catboost) at the top of the script is enough to later on a shiny.io server produce the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @IRTFM that the `devtools::install_github` is needed, or even better its source the `remotes::install_github`. But it is not so apparent that you must use the `subdir` option.

When you use the `remotes::install_github`, additional Remotes/Github fields are added to the package DESCRIPTION file. Thus later, the `packrat` or `renv` can handle such dependencies properly.

Please validate the additional Remotes/Github fields.

```r
# remotes::install_github('catboost/catboost', ref = "v1.1.1", subdir = 'catboost/R-package', INSTALL_opts = c("--no-multiarch"))
packageDescription("catboost")
#> Package: catboost
#> Title: Gradient Boosting on Decision Trees
#> Version: 1.1.1
#> RoxygenNote: 7.1.2
#> Imports: jsonlite
#> License: Apache License (== 2.0)
#> Description: Open-source gradient boosting on decision trees with
#>         categorical features support out of the box.
#> Authors@R: c( person("Nikita", "Dmitriev", role = "aut"),
#>         person("Andrey", "Gulin", role = "aut", comment = "Chief
#>         researcher, author of the algorithm and of the first
#>         implementation"), person("Anna Veronika", "Dorogush", role =
#>         "aut"), person("Stanislav", "Kirillov", role = "cre", email =
#>         "staskirillov@gmail.com"), person("Victor", "Omelyanenko", role
#>         = "aut"), person("Evgueni", "Petrov", role = "aut"),
#>         person("Andrey", "Mishenko", role = "aut"), person("Pavel",
#>         "Kalinin", role = "aut"), person("Vyacheslav", "Alipov", role =
#>         "aut"), person("Egor", "Samosvat", role = "aut"),
#>         person("Alexander", "Kobotov", role = "aut"), person("Dmitry",
#>         "Schelchkov", role = "aut"), person("Vasily", "Ershov", role =
#>         "aut", comment = "GPU implementation"), person("Vyacheslav",
#>         "Murashkin", role = "aut", comment = "R Package"),
#>         person("Roman", "Nefyodov", role = "aut", comment = "R
#>         Package"), person("Anastasia", "Bezzubtseva", role = "aut",
#>         comment = "R Package"), person("Alexey", "Gorchakov", role =
#>         "aut", comment = "R Package"), person("Ivan", "Karev", role =
#>         "aut", comment = "Visualisation"), person("Sergey",
#>         "Berezhnoy", role = "aut", comment = "Visualisation"),
#>         person("Roman", "Rybalchenko", role = "aut", comment =
#>         "Visualisation"), person("Valeriy", "Babushkin", role = "aut",
#>         comment = "Tutorials"), person("Mikhail", "Pershin", role =
#>         "aut", comment = "Tutorials"), person("Emil", "Kayumov", role =
#>         "aut", comment = "Tutorials"), person("Evgeny", "Eltyshev",
#>         role = "aut", comment = "Tutorials"), person("Alexander",
#>         "Baranov", role = "aut", comment = "CoreML support"),
#>         person("Dmitry", "Oganesyan", role = "aut", comment = "R
#>         Package"), person("CatBoost DevTeam", role = c("aut", "cph")),
#>         person("WLOG Solutions", role = "ctb", comment = "R package
#>         preparation for CRAN submission"), person("Dmitry", "Baksheev",
#>         role = "aut") )
#> Author: CatBoost DevTeam [aut, cre]
#> Maintainer: Stanislav Kirillov <staskirillov@gmail.com>
#> URL: https://catboost.ai/, https://github.com/catboost/catboost
#> BugReports: https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues
#> Suggests: caret, testthat, tibble, e1071
#> Biarch: FALSE
#> Encoding: UTF-8
#> RemoteType: github
#> RemoteHost: api.github.com
#> RemoteRepo: catboost
#> RemoteUsername: catboost
#> RemoteRef: HEAD
#> RemoteSha: 7d926816beea530ea97873323f5848fff7c9b474
#> RemoteSubdir: catboost/R-package
#> GithubRepo: catboost
#> GithubUsername: catboost
#> GithubRef: HEAD
#> GithubSHA1: 7d926816beea530ea97873323f5848fff7c9b474
#> GithubSubdir: catboost/R-package
#> NeedsCompilation: yes
#> Packaged: 2023-03-18 11:12:33 UTC; maciejnasinski
#> Built: R 4.2.2; aarch64-apple-darwin20; 2023-03-18 11:12:37 UTC; unix
#> 
#> -- File: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/catboost/Meta/package.rds
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>